# C# ASP.NET - Dynamic MenuItems in a user control are randomly being duplicated outside of control creation

Tags: c#, asp.net, tabs, user-controls, menuitem

**EDIT: I needed to skip control creation during post back -- see my answer below.**

I'm working on a very basic front end to a simple tool and I wanted to present some data in a much more sorted and useful way, instead of making one huge wall of text.  I found [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13165/A-Simple-ASP-NET-Tab-Control-Using-the-MultiView-c) on building a simple tabbed interface using MultiView, but have run into a bizarre problem.  I can't use Ajax tabs because of legal hissy fits over 3rd party software.

My webpage is a basic ASP.NET page with a user control plopped in the middle of it.  In this control's ascx file, I defined the Menu (empty) and the MultiView (also empty) so that I can dynamically populate the tabs with content driven from an external file.

When the default page's OnInitComplete function is called, I call through to the user control to load the data file, then build out the tabs and the view content based on the loaded data.  I tried doing this from PageLoad, PreInit, and CreateChildControls, but I kept getting an errors saying that I was setting the the MultiView's active view index at an invalid time (and also that there were 0 views despite the fact I just added a bunch of them):

> ActiveViewIndex is being set to '0'. It must be smaller than the
>   current number of View controls '0'. For dynamically added views, make
>   sure they are added before or in Page_PreInit event.

But OnInitComplete appears to work just fine, so I went with that.

I iterate over the loaded data (multiple lists of strings), and for each list, I add a MenuItem with the list's title to the Menu and a View to the MultiView.  The View is populated with a table->row->cell as in the above tutorial.  In the cell, I add the list title and a CheckBoxList data bound to the list of strings.

So far so good, but when I click on a tab (or one of the checkboxes, etc) and there is a postback or something like that (the screen flashes as the site redraws itself), there is now a duplicate set of MenuItems immediately after the original.  Each time I click on a tab or checkbox, another set of menu items are added.

I clear the MenuItem's Items list prior to building the controls and I verify that the controls hierarchy is structurally as expected after the control construction.  Yet when one of my callbacks is called, my MenuItem list magically has some items added to it.  None of my other controls appear affected at all.  As a hack, I can remove the duplicates manually in my menu's OnMenuItemClick event, but I'd have to do the same in any of the callbacks I receive.  Obviously I'd rather prevent this from happening.  This has me stumped and I haven't been able to find anything online about it.  Why would one set of controls have some content duplicated, yet every other control maintain its state correctly?  My code is really simple so there isn't a way to add additional menu items without also adding the views.  Anyway, there are a correct number of items prior to clicking on the tab/checkbox, an additional set immediately following in the callback.

This is my first time using ASP.NET, so I'm learning as I go.  :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I was not testing for postback before creating the controls.  The code below is working for me.

In my user control's code behind:

```
protected void OnInitComplete( EventArgs e )
{
    if( !Page.IsPostBack )
    {
        CreateMyControls();
    }
}
```